# delay in excution of my php code in linux cli

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, delay, centos7

I  have a centOs7 Server with php v5.4.16 when i want to excute a php code in command line(#php mycode.php)  , there is an approximate 3 or 4 second delay in execution of  php code.what is the reason of this delay?

[my php.ini file](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8351860668/php.ini.html)

Comment: Is there any heavy code in your php file ?

Comment: no my code very simple,for example :
`code`<?php echo "hello"; ?>, when i execute my code in cli , the response appear after hitting Enter Key for several times,that is the page is blank for some seconds

Comment: even this command answers with delay: #php -v

Comment: Please test it by : ```/usr/bin/php yourfile.php```

Comment: this command did not work as well

Comment: Could you share your **php.ini** file ?

Comment: I Enclosed  my php.ini file in top in My Question part

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the PHP binary taking a few seconds to start and initalise. You would not use the PHP binary as the actual Server, but XAMP, LAMP, etc. There isn't much you can do about this except to set up an actual server with live reload and look at the code in a browser.